# Which IP alias is currently active

Tags: python, centos

I used ip aliasing technique to assign multiple ips on single nic. I am using these ips in a python script to generate traffic. I am doing this for my college project. Can anyone tell me that how would I come to know that currently in my script which IP is used to generate traffic? I am using centos 6.5

Answer (score 1):

You can get the local IP and port used for the socket by doing

```
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53))
>>> sock.getsockname()
('192.168.1.67', 36498)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention this before, but actually my client is not connected to internet. It in instead connected to one internal network consisting of just my client and my server. so sock.connect is not working for me. is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: here trying to connect to my own server and then executing sock.getsockname, everytime returns just the ip of eth0 only. though when i check in pcap file, traffic has been generated by all the aliased ips i.e. from eth0:1,eth0:2,eth0:3,etc. Is there any other way of identifying which ip alias is currently active?

Comment: Dont know why was this question closed????? Found answer: Used multiprocesssing.Process instead of threading.Thread then using len(psutil.pids()) to find out number of active clients since here in my case number of active clients=number of processes